# Program not counting -2 at the smallest integer when in the array 10,-2,-1

Tags: java, arrays

For some reason, whenever I compile and run this code I get correct answers on what the lowest number in the array is. UNLESS I type in 10, -2, and -1. At this point, it gives me -1 as the smallest number when instead it should be -2. It seems the first number doesn't seem to matter much so long as it is positive. It seems like the program is reading the array wrong, but I'm not sure how to change it.

```
import java.util.Scanner; public class Problem { 
public static void main(String[] arg) 
{
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
System.out.println("Insert three integers, USER.");
int x = scan.nextInt();
int y = scan.nextInt();
int z = scan.nextInt();
//returns smallest, tried to keep code short with arrays 
int array[] = new int[]{x,y,z};
int small = array[0];
int box=2;
if (array[box]<small) {
    small = array[box];
}
```

I think it has something to do with     int small = array[0]; because whenever I change it it sort of skews the problem to other numbers. Like the program is reading only a certain group of integers and ignoring the rest.

Comment: Where in the code do you look at `array[1]`?

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense for what you are trying to do. You only ever look at the first and third elements...

Comment: `array[0] = 10`, `array[1] = -2`, `array[2] = -1`. `if (array[box]<small) {` where `box = 2` then you're comparing: `-1 < 10` so it returns `-1` 'cause you never compare `array[1]` wich is -2 in your code.

Comment: How would I cause it to look at all elements? I figured that was happening but couldn't figure out a solution with the little I know.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't iterating through the array, so the second number never gets compared; try this:

```
int array[] = new int[]{x,y,z};
int small = array[0];
for(i = 1; i < array[].length; i++) {
     if (array[i] < small) {
         small = array[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem appears to be a fundamental misunderstanding of iteration. In the code that you posted, you are only ever comparing the values of two elements in your array, i.e. `array[0]`, and the element at `box`, which is `array[2]`. Therefore, in your example, "comparing" 10, -2, and -1, you're only actually comparing 10 to -1.

I think what you intended to do was look at each element in the array sequentially. This is most easily done using a `for-loop`, as:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] < small)
        small = array[i];
}
```

On the first iteration (`i == 0`), you compare 10 to 10, so `small` remains the same. On the second iteration (`i == 1`) you compare 10 to -2, and so `small` is assigned the value -2. On the third iteration you compare -2 to -1, so once again `small` remains the same. As `i == 2`, the termination condition is met, and the loop ceases.

For more info, see the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) on `for-loop`s.

Answer (score 0):

You are only checking 2 of the numbers entered.

> int small = array[0];

Checks the first element at 0, then you reference the third element with

> int box=2;

You need to loop through and check all elements because the second is being skipped.